# ByteBuffer - convert long to char array and vice versa

Tags: java, bytebuffer

I am trying to convert a long to a 4 char array.

It seems like the last char is not being written to the buffer.

Why is this not working?

```
//convert long to char array

long longValZ = 219902744986400000L;

ByteBuffer bbX = ByteBuffer.allocate(8);
bbX.putLong(longValZ); 
//longValZ = 219902744986400000

char [] charArr1 = new char[4];
charArr1[0] = bbX.getChar(0);
charArr1[1] = bbX.getChar(1);
charArr1[2] = bbX.getChar(2);
charArr1[3] = bbX.getChar(3);

long longValX = bbX.getLong(0); 
//longValX = 219902744986400000


//convert char array to long

ByteBuffer bbY = ByteBuffer.allocate(8);

bbY.putChar(0,charArr1[0]);
bbY.putChar(1,charArr1[1]);
bbY.putChar(2,charArr1[2]);
bbY.putChar(3,charArr1[3]);

long longValY = bbY.getLong(0); 
//longValY = 219902744985600000 --> why is longValY different than longValZ ?
```

Comment: The indices in `getChar` are still byte-sized.

Comment: In other words, you need to get 2 bytes (for each `char`) at indices 0, 2, 4, and 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to provide the index

```
long longValZ = 219902744986400000L;

ByteBuffer bbX = ByteBuffer.allocate(8);
bbX.putLong(longValZ); 

char[] charArr1 = new char[4];
for (int i = 0; i < charArr1.length; i++)
   charArr1[i] = bbX.getChar();



//convert char array to long

ByteBuffer bbY = ByteBuffer.allocate(8);
for (int i = 0; i < charArr1.length; i++)
    bbY.putChar(charArr1[i]);

long longValY = bbY.getLong(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Sotirios, here is the correct answer:

```
//convert long to char array

long longValZ = 219902744986400000L;

ByteBuffer bbX = ByteBuffer.allocate(8);
bbX.putLong(longValZ); 

char [] charArr1 = new char[4];
charArr1[0] = bbX.getChar(0);
charArr1[1] = bbX.getChar(2);
charArr1[2] = bbX.getChar(4);
charArr1[3] = bbX.getChar(6);



//convert char array to long

ByteBuffer bbY = ByteBuffer.allocate(8);
bbY.putChar(0,charArr1[0]);
bbY.putChar(2,charArr1[1]);
bbY.putChar(4,charArr1[2]);
bbY.putChar(6,charArr1[3]);

long longValY = bbY.getLong(0);
```